# Creating a tsql query to group history of receipts(individual IDs) as the same base on the column descriptions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am brand new to this website. I've been searching for answers of my problem and could not find a solution so I created an account hoping someone will guide me or show me to the right path. Here is the business problem: We have receipts that can be printed with Value amount and can also be inserted in machines to redeem the value amount. So a user will say print a receipt from machine 1 that holds 20 dollars, insert it to machine 2 to 'Play'the 20 dollars, then print out the remaining value if not all are used as a receipt. For simplicity, i will be removing Play transaction and only leaving the inserted and print transaction:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTable') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable(LocationNo Int, SessionNo Int, ReceiptNo Varchar(MAX), TransDateTime DateTime, Value Decimal, EventDescription VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #MyTable 
VALUES (02, 888888, '1A1A1A', '2017-08-27 12:18:10.000', '20.00', 'Printed'),
(01, 111111, '1A1A1A', '2017-08-27 12:18:11.000', '20.00', 'Inserted'),
(01, 111111, '2A2A2A', '2017-08-27 12:18:59.000', '20.00', 'Printed'),

(01, 555555, '1B1B1B', '2017-08-27 09:18:11.000', '100.00', 'Printed'),

(03, 222222, '2A2A2A', '2017-08-30 04:59:02.000', '20.00', 'Inserted'),
(03, 222222, '3A3A3A', '2017-08-30 04:59:10.000', '10.00', 'Printed'),
(03, 222222, '4A4A4A', '2017-08-30 04:59:11.000', '10.00', 'Printed'),

(05, 999999, '1B1B1B', '2017-08-29 11:59:30.000', '100.00', 'Inserted'),
(05, 999999, '2B2B2B', '2017-08-29 11:59:32.000', '50.00', 'Printed'),

(07, 777777, '1C1C1C', '2017-08-27 11:59:30.000', '20.00', 'Printed'),

(08, 444444, '4A4A4A', '2017-09-02 07:00:30.000', '10.00', 'Inserted'),
(08, 444444, '5A5A5A', '2017-09-02 07:00:40.000', '9.00', 'Printed')



;


Select * from #MyTable


DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

Producing this table:

```
LocationNo  SessionNo  ReceiptNo    TransDateTime   Value   EventDescription
2   888888  1A1A1A  2017-08-27 12:18:10.000 20  Printed
1   111111  1A1A1A  2017-08-27 12:18:11.000 20  Inserted
1   111111  2A2A2A  2017-08-27 12:18:59.000 20  Printed
1   555555  1B1B1B  2017-08-27 09:18:11.000 100 Printed
3   222222  2A2A2A  2017-08-30 04:59:02.000 20  Inserted
3   222222  3A3A3A  2017-08-30 04:59:10.000 10  Printed
3   222222  4A4A4A  2017-08-30 04:59:11.000 10  Printed
5   999999  1B1B1B  2017-08-29 11:59:30.000 100 Inserted
5   999999  2B2B2B  2017-08-29 11:59:32.000 50  Printed
7   777777  1C1C1C  2017-08-27 11:59:30.000 20  Printed
8   444444  4A4A4A  2017-09-02 07:00:30.000 10  Inserted
8   444444  5A5A5A  2017-09-02 07:00:40.000 9   Printed
```

If we follow say Receipt 1A1A1A, we see that it happens first in SessionNo 888888. SessionNo represent multiple transactions consisting of inserted and printed receipts. A person can insert then print is one Session. That same Receipt 1A1A1A will then be inserted in Machine 1 (Row 2). looking at SessionNo 11111 you will see that user inserted the 1a1a1a receipt in machine 1, then printed out the value which now becomes receipt 2A2A2A.. 2A2A2A got inserted in machine 3 (row 5), then printed out as two Receipts as 3A3A3A and 4A4A4A, and so on... But all through that process, we know that 1a1a1a are the same receipt as 2A2A2A, which is the same receipt as (3A3A3A and 4A4A4A). Basically, what I want is a query that creates a temporary id to group these multiple transaction of receipts as same receipts - showing the history of receipts being converted from inserted to being printed as new receipt No. Ultimately, I want to see this result:

```
TempID  LocationNo  SessionNo   ReceiptNo   TransDateTime   Value   EventDescription
123 2   888888  1A1A1A  2017-08-27 12:18:10.000 20  Printed
123 1   111111  1A1A1A  2017-08-27 12:18:11.000 20  Inserted
123 1   111111  2A2A2A  2017-08-27 12:18:59.000 20  Printed
123 3   222222  2A2A2A  2017-08-30 04:59:02.000 20  Inserted
123 3   222222  3A3A3A  2017-08-30 04:59:10.000 10  Printed
123 3   222222  4A4A4A  2017-08-30 04:59:11.000 10  Printed
123 8   444444  4A4A4A  2017-09-02 07:00:30.000 10  Inserted
123 8   444444  5A5A5A  2017-09-02 07:00:40.000 9   Printed
245 1   555555  1B1B1B  2017-08-27 09:18:11.000 100 Printed
245 5   999999  1B1B1B  2017-08-29 11:59:30.000 100 Inserted
245 5   999999  2B2B2B  2017-08-29 11:59:32.000 50  Printed
679 7   777777  1C1C1C  2017-08-27 11:59:30.000 20  Printed
```

Comment: Can't you simply store the original receipt number in every print action?

Comment: @ZoharPeled thats what I wish as well, unfortunately this is customers data. Also, receipts sometimes split, so receipt 2a2a2a got inserted as 20 amount, and spits out to multiples as 3a3a3a, 4a4a4a

Comment: I've done something similar a few years back. It's a bit hard to remember now, but I think I just kept the previous receipt number for each new receipt and used a recursive cte to get specific receipt history. It's past midnight here so it's kinda hard for me to recreate it using your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is using a couple of common table expressions.
The first cte gets the previous receipt number of the current session, and the previous session of the current receipt using `lag`, and the second cte is a recursive cte, using the first cte as base.

The key part here is to identify the first record for each receipt - and use these records as the anchor part of the recursive cte.

This will result with the first `ReceiptNo` for each receipt as a unique identifier for the entire receipt history. Finally, select distinct from the recursive cte to get the results. (You might need to add `option (MaxRecursion 0)` to the query if you have a lot of traffic for the same receipt)

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  LocationNo, 
            SessionNo, 
            ReceiptNo, 
            TransDateTime, 
            Value, 
            EventDescription,
            LAG(ReceiptNo) OVER(PARTITION BY SessionNo ORDER BY TransDateTime) AS prevReceiptNo,
            LAG(SessionNo) OVER(PARTITION BY ReceiptNo ORDER BY TransDateTime) AS prevSessionNo
    FROM #MyTable t0
), CTE2 AS
    (
    SELECT  *, ReceiptNo As OriginalReceiptNo
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE prevReceiptNo IS NULL 
    AND prevSessionNo IS NULL
    UNION ALL

    SELECT CTE1.*, OriginalReceiptNo
    FROM CTE1
    JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.prevReceiptNo = CTE2.ReceiptNo OR CTE1.prevSessionNo = CTE2.SessionNo
)

SELECT DISTINCT LocationNo, 
            SessionNo, 
            ReceiptNo, 
            TransDateTime, 
            Value, 
            EventDescription,
            OriginalReceiptNo
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY OriginalReceiptNo, TransDateTime
```

Results:

```
LocationNo  SessionNo   ReceiptNo   TransDateTime           Value   EventDescription    OriginalReceiptNo
2           888888      1A1A1A      27.08.2017 12:18:10     20      Printed             1A1A1A
1           111111      1A1A1A      27.08.2017 12:18:11     20      Inserted            1A1A1A
1           111111      2A2A2A      27.08.2017 12:18:59     20      Printed             1A1A1A
3           222222      2A2A2A      30.08.2017 04:59:02     20      Inserted            1A1A1A
3           222222      3A3A3A      30.08.2017 04:59:10     10      Printed             1A1A1A
3           222222      4A4A4A      30.08.2017 04:59:11     10      Printed             1A1A1A
8           444444      4A4A4A      02.09.2017 07:00:30     10      Inserted            1A1A1A
8           444444      5A5A5A      02.09.2017 07:00:40     9       Printed             1A1A1A
1           555555      1B1B1B      27.08.2017 09:18:11     100     Printed             1B1B1B
5           999999      1B1B1B      29.08.2017 11:59:30     100     Inserted            1B1B1B
5           999999      2B2B2B      29.08.2017 11:59:32     50      Printed             1B1B1B
7           777777      1C1C1C      27.08.2017 11:59:30     20      Printed             1C1C1C
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZQPPCV98877)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for. It took some time to understand the recursive idea, but it make sense.

Comment: Glad to help :-).